# My telegram bot is not responding after I click on a button

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, telebot

I have a telegram bot (I'm using the telebot library) that's integrated with Firebase (especifically with Firestore Database). The bot asks the user if they want to know the power consumed in a room or of a specific device inside a room - the device feature has not been implemented yet. When you click Room, it finds all the rooms (that are documents inside a collection) and sends a button for every room it found.

The issue is that when you choose a room the bot should send you the total fo the field 'potencia' of all the subcollections and documents found inside that room but the bot never responds and I found that it's because it never enters to the callback function but I have no idea why.

Here's the code I'm using
TOKEN and fire_add are variables that have the token of the bot and the address of the .json file with the Firebase credentials

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
import telebot
from telebot import types
from datetime import datetime

# Initialize the connection to Firebase
cred = credentials.Certificate(fire_add)
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()

# Initialize the connection to Telegram
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

# Handle the /start command
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.row(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Room', callback_data='Room'),
               types.InlineKeyboardButton('Device', callback_data='Device'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Do you want to know the power consumption of a room or a specific device?", reply_markup=markup)

# Handle the selection of Room or Device
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_query(call):
    if call.data == 'Room':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        # Get all the rooms from the 'vivienda1' collection
        rooms = db.collection('vivienda1').get()
        # Create a button for each room
        for room in rooms:
            markup.row(types.InlineKeyboardButton(room.id, callback_data='Room:' + room.id))
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Which room do you want to know the power consumption of?", reply_markup=markup)
    elif call.data == 'Device':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Functionality not yet implemented")

# Handle the selection of a specific room
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data.startswith('Room:'))
def room_query(call):
    room = call.data.split(':')[1]
    total_power = 0
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    # Get all the subcollections within the selected room
    subcollections = db.collection('vivienda1').document(room).collections()
    # Sum the power consumption of all subcollections for today
    for subcollection in subcollections:
        docs = subcollection.where('fecha', '==', today).get()
        for doc in docs:
            total_power += doc.to_dict().get('potencia', 0)
    # Return an array with the name of the room and the total power consumption for today
    array = [{'room': room}, {'total_power': total_power}]
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, str(array))

# Start the bot
bot.polling()
```

I added some prints to the call back fundtion but it's not entering in def room_query(call)

Answer (score 0):

`def room_query(call):` is not triggered because of `def callback_query(call):`

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_query(call):
```

Your handler for callback_query is shadowing handler for room_query because it accepts all calls `(func=lambda call: True)`
You should just put room_query function before callback_query.

Comment: I fixed it by adding different elif's into the @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True). So it enters multiple times to that callback function and then searches for the right response between the if/else. Is that ok or is it a bad practice for bots?